# Is it possible to walk along the coast from Barcelona to Gibraltar?

Tags: spain, backpacking, barcelona, coastline

I am thinking to make a walking trip along the sea from Barcelona south to the Strait of Gibraltar.

I used Google Maps and I saw that it offered me almost all highways. Is it even possible to walk on highways in Spain? I wouldn't like to walk along these noisy, crowded roads. How could I get to the south on roads with much less traffic?

Comment: It looks to me like it it's mostly suggesting small roads or footpaths that are in many cases adjacent to highways.

Comment: I don't know, man. N-340 doesn't look like a small road to me. I am looking for footpaths, but I can't see.

Comment: Searching "sea walk path barcelona to gibraltar" produced [Barcelona to Gibraltar (organised holiday) Cycling Route](http://www.holidaysbycycle.com/barcelona-to-gibraltar-organised-holiday-93-cycling-route) and although it takes a detour inland to Ronda, perhaps you can refine the search, or look at more detailed maps day by day.

Comment: Yeah, it can help but just a little bit. The map is based on only a straight red line in airway. It is something but I need something more. Any other idea? Do you know someone on the Internet that did something similar to me and wrote a blog or something? Or any of you?

Comment: There is little detail here in a section of the route [180km of Malaga coastal path](http://www.andalucia.org/en/articles/180-kilometres-of-mediterranean-along-the-malaga-coastal-path/) but perhaps you can explore further.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is quite a bit of coastal private property and military installations you'd have to bypass by walking a bit inland.

Answer (score 5):

There is a hiking trail intended to follow the Mediterranean coast from the Pyrenees to the Strait of Gibraltar, [GR-92](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/GR_92). The Andalusian part of it seems to be still incomplete, but as far as I can see in the links the Catalan and Valencian parts are ready, and from personal experience I can tell you that some parts in Catalonia were actually completed more than 20 years ago.

Comment: _some parts in Catalonia were actually completed more than 20 years ago_. Indeed, since its name is after Barcelona Olympics in 92 and the goal was to have it completed by that year.

Comment: @fedorqui - As far as I can remember, the goal of complete the route from the Pyrenees to Barcelona by the Olympic Games, wasn't complete in 1992. However, at least the track in Collserola (between Besòs and Llobregat rivers) was complete: I still have the guide I used to walk it and its dated in 1992.

Answer (score 4):

On foot, Google maps gives more than 800 directions to make the journey from [Barcelona to Gibraltar](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Barcelona,+Spain/Gibraltar/@41.3850808,2.1733913,17z/am=t/data=!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x12a49816718e30e5:0x44b0fb3d4f47660a!2m2!1d2.1734035!2d41.3850639!1m5!1m1!1s0xd0cbf762714be35:0x384e25263600870f!2m2!1d-5.353585!2d36.140751!3e2!6m3!1i0!2i0!3i0), a distance of some 1100 km (and 218 hours non-stop). If that map option doesn’t suit, you could blaze your own trail (and blog about it), leaving Barcelona southwest of the airport and following the coastline, keeping the sea in sight as you go. A coastal route would add both time and distance to the journey. It would help to have a GPS navigation system.

This response in [SE The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/good-quality-walking-maps-for-spain) offered information on good quality walking maps for Spain and the @gerrit suggestion that

> [Wikiloc](http://www.wikiloc.com/) is very popular in Spain. Pretty much anywhere you'll go you'll find hundreds of GPS-trails. Even if you do not use a GPS-receiver, you can use those in combination with your map to find out where the trails are. It requires good planning and it's helpful to have access to internet while on your trip.